# What is the best way to keep local copy of Firebase Database on node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app where I need to check people's posts constantly. I am trying to make sure that the -server- handles more than 100,000 posts. I tried to explain the program and specify the issues I am worried about by numbers.

I am running a **simple node.js program** on my terminal that runs as firebase admin controlling the Firebase Database. The program has no connectivity with clients(users), **it just keeps the database locally to check users' posts every 2-3 seconds**. I am keeping the posts in local hash variables by using on('child_added') to simply push the post to a posts hash and so on for on('child_removed') and on('child_changed').

1. Are these functions able to handle more than 5 requests per second?
2. Is this the **proper way of keeping data locally for faster processing(and not abusing firebase limits)**? I need to check every post on the platform every 2-3 seconds, so I am trying to keep a local copy of the -posts data.

   That local copy of the posts are looped through every 2-3 seconds.
3. If there are thousands of posts, will a simple array variable handle that load?

**Second part of the program:**

I run a for loop to loop through the posts in a function. I run the function every 2-3 seconds using setInterval(). The program needs not only to check new added posts but it constantly needs to check all posts on the database.

If(specific condition for a post) => the program changes the state of the post

.on(child_changed) function => sends an API request to a website after that state change

4. Can this function run asynchronously ? When it is called, the function should not wait for the previous call to finish because the old call is sending an API request and it might not complete fast. **How can I make sure that .on(child_changed) doesn't miss a single change on the -posts data?**

Answer (score 1):

[Listen for Value Events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) documentation shows how to observe changes, namely one uses the `.on` method.

In terms of backing up your Realtime Database, you simply export the data manually, or if  you have the paid plan [you can automate it](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/announcing-automated-daily-backups-for-the-firebase-database.html).

I don't understand why you would want to recreate the wheel, so to speak, and have your server ping firebase for updates. Simply use firebase observers.

Comment: I already stated that I'm using the observer methods. I am not talking about a backup, but the speed of accessing the data

Comment: [Realtime Database Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits) 100,000/second is not fast enough?

Comment: the issue here is not Firebase's database power, it is the node.js app handling too many changes on the database and catching every change